# How to ask for a file in Python?

Tags: python

I have an interact() function which I need to ask for a file. I already have a function load_maze(filename) which loads my text document in python. How do i get interact() to ask for my filename in load_maze(filename)?

Comment: How does your program, uh, interact with the user?

Comment: Is this commandline or graphical if so which framework are you using?

Comment: I think you need to provide a little bit more information on what your problem is.  It sounds like interact is a custom function, if so you need to let everyone know what it is supposed to do. Also letting everyone know what you have attempted will be a great help.  If you are simply trying to get user input from the command line then you can look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-and-user-input

Comment: @ ignacio When I run interact(), the user has to type the filename they want to load. I'll try to be more precise. e.g raw_input("Maze File:") maze1.txt.  I want the user to define a text document i have created.

Comment: Could you show us the existing code of `interact()`? Could you show the code that arranges for `interact()` to get called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anthony, maybe something like this?:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def interact():
    fn = raw_input("Enter a filename: ")
    return fn

def load_maze(fn):
    myfile = open(fn)
    maze_txt = myfile.read()
    myfile.close()
    return maze_txt

print load_maze(interact())
```

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your program. The easiest interaction I could imagine is asking for it in the console. Use `raw_input`.

```
response = raw_input('give me a file name')
```

if you are using py3k beware because `raw_input()` is now `input()`. `input()` is also in py2k but there it has a different behavior than `raw_input.`

Comment: @ joaquin If i use that code, how do i get python to open the response (in your example)

Comment: @icktoofay thanks, yes it was ambiguous. hope now is more clear.

Comment: @AnthonyDo I am not sure what do you mean. `response` is the name of a variable that holds wathever you entered in the console. Then you should use your function: `load_maze(response)`