# how to ask for user input in a function. Python related

Tags: python

Is there a way to ask for user input while defining a function?
for example here's a simple function:

```
def sum3(a,b,c):
    add=a+b+c
    return add
```

in the above code, is there a way I can ask the user to
enter 3 numbers.
say, when the program runs
the user sees a prompt saying "please enter 3 numbers"

Comment: You can use [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) function.. Had you googled the topic, you would have got this as your first link..

Comment: Rohit, I know about raw_input what I want to know is how to ask for the input within this function. so that when function runs, user is asked for input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python and User input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-and-user-input)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def sum3():
    print "Please enter three numbers:"
    a = input()
    b = input()
    c = input()
    return sum((a,b,c)) # a+b+c

print sum3() # asks for input then prints result.
```

*Note: we use the built-in [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) function.*

Comment: well, I know about the built in function but what I want to know is how to ask for the user input. I know about raw input also.
but what I want to know is how to edit the above code so as to ask for user input.
I mean I could ask for user input if I was not using this function. but I dont know how to ask for user input within a function.

is there something like

        def sum3("enter 3 numbers:";a,b,c)

Comment: You should not use `input` with Python 2.x.