# Input And Print In Python

Tags: python

I am making a simple text based game but I can't even get past the second line of code.  My code so far looks like this:

```
print("Welcome To City Text!  First You Must Name Your City.")
```

Then the person is supposed to type a name and the shell will print "Welcome To "Town Name" City" The problem is I don't know how to do this.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Was asked many times, i.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-and-user-input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the fact that you're using `print("text")` rather than `print "text"`, I assume you're using Python 3.x rather than Python 2.x. In that case, `raw_input` won't work, because that was renamed [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) (the original `input` function did [something else](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), and was removed entirely).

So, if you're getting a NameError when you use `raw_input`, just replace it with `input`.

(If you *aren't* getting a NameError, you're using Python 2.x, and you should leave out the parenthesis around the string you're printing; in Python 2.x, `print` is a [statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement), not a function. It will still work with the parentheses, but it's just going to create confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

The line raw_input() lets you get the input from the console. The argument you pass it is the line it prints before getting the input. So your code would look something like this:

```
var_name=raw_input("Welcome To City Text! First You Must Name Your City.")
```

this will print: Welcome To City Text! First You Must Name Your City. then let you type until you hit enter and return what you typed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x=raw_input()` to get a string from the keyboard.

If you google "python input text from console" you will get lots of answers.

You can put the result into another string using

```
print("hello %s." % x)
```

You can also use

```
print("hello "+x+".")
```

which does more or less the same thing.

You can find more about this by googling for "formatting strings in python" or "concatenating strings in python"

Comment: In Python 3, this is `x = input()` and `"hello {}.".format(x)`.