# while loop input Yes/No (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, operands

This is the code :

```
quiz = str(input("would you like to answer some questions \n choose y/n"))

quiz = quiz.lower()
while quiz != 'y' or quiz != 'n':
    print("please choose 'y' or 'n'")
    input("y/n?")
```

This is part of my code I have tried using `str()` even without `or` operand it is not working btw I am using python `v3.7`.

1) If you can please fix the code

2) If you know some other code is more efficient tell

Note: If the input is y. # for example
error is `" ValueError: float: Argument: y is not a number "`

Comment: `quiz = quiz.lowercase()` ... the `str` call is unnecessary, and the `or` in the while condition should be `and`

Comment: What about `and`? Or `quiz not in ('y', 'n')`.

Comment: wasn't it ```lower()``` instead of ```lowercase()```?

Comment: Yeah Xosrov, sorry it was lower() in my code here I made the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//This code is for explanation 

quiz = str(input("would you like to answer some questions \n choose y/n"))

quiz = quiz.lower()

while quiz != 'y' and quiz != 'n': //here you are using != that will result false this logic works fine with !

//while quiz == 'y' or quiz == 'n': //will work for or

print("please choose 'y' or 'n'")

input("y/n?")

//this code will work 

quiz = str(input("would you like to answer some questions \n choose y/n"))

quiz = quiz.lower()

while quiz != 'y' and quiz != 'n':

   print("please choose 'y' or 'n'")

   input("y/n?")
```

I hope this helps.

You may be interested in flow charts or Algorithms please follow this link: https://www.edrawsoft.com/explain-algorithm-flowchart.php

You may also be interested to learn about python more please follow this link: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Thank you.

Comment: And yes ValueError still remains is there a way to finish it

Comment: I added the final part please copy the code below comment stating //this code will work and paste it on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler

No value error in the shared code

Answer (score 0):

Input looks for an integer, raw input will receive a string. Try using

`raw_input(y/n)`

This should clear the `ValueError`

Comment: Sorry, missed that the op was using 3

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
def check_input(predicate, msg, error_string="Illegal Input"):
    while True:
        result = input(msg).strip()
        if predicate(result):
            return result
        print(error_string)

result = check_input(lambda x: x in ['yes', 'no'],
                                   'Yes or no?')
print(result)
```

Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16884735/8671871)