# How can i ask for user input and use that input for this text summarizer i created?

Tags: python, text

I have created a text summarizer based on a code I found on Github. I'm trying to have to script ask for the title for the text and ask for the actual text.

```
title =    """ """

content = """
As metro Atlanta's weather and road conditions continue to thaw after this week's snowstorm, MARTA is planning modified bus and Mobility (paratransit) service starting tomorrow, initially on 30 "life-line" routes. MARTA's rail service will continue operating on a weekend schedule on all lines.

Bus and Mobility service will start at 7 a.m. Friday and run until 11:30 p.m. (See below for preliminary list of restored bus routes or visit MARTA's website: itsmarta.com.) The first round of bus routes being restored provide transit access to some of the region's major hospitals, job centers and commercial corridors. Customers may experience extended waits on some routes are asked to please allow extra time to complete their trips. Based on specific road and traffic conditions, more routes may be added throughout the day and real-time adjustments to the bus schedule are possible.

MARTA rail service will begin for customers at 4:35 a.m. Friday and run until about 2 a.m. on Saturday. Customers should mostly expect wait times for trains ranging from 10 to 20 minutes – conditions permitting. Since some rail stations are open to the elements, customers are advised to dress accordingly.

"""
```

^ that's what I have in the code: where Title is, you input the title. content is the text the user would want summarized.

If you want a demo: you can go to http://runnable.com/Uv1foJAZ0BxuAABl/summerizer-for-python and click run.

How can i have the program ask for the title and the content?

Comment: Please... What is the problem you are facing? And what did you try? This question have 12 to many lines, and 1 missing example of what you have tried.

Comment: i have tried title = input ("enter title here") and content = input ("enter text to be summarized here")

Comment: In this case it is very useful to indicate what version of python you're using - as user3193087 indicated below, it is different in python 2.x and 3.x

Answer (score 3):

In python 2.x, you can do:

```
usertext = raw_input("message here")
```

for python 3.x:

```
usertext = input("message here")
```

Comment: nice comparison between python 2x and 3x

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a way to get user inputs as to the title and the content?

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

```
title = raw_input("Please input your title here: ")
content = raw_input("Please enter your content here: ")
```

EDIT: Duplicate of [Python: user input and commandline arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-and-user-input), more or less

Comment: I did that but got a error message 

something about a indentation error: unexpected indent for st = summary tool

Comment: @user3213259 well as you can see, there are no indents in my code.  An indent error is likely coming from a different part of your code

Comment: i just added your code to the script on that site you can view it and see what i talking about

Comment: @user3213259 Look at the code you added. Note that they are indented differently.  They should have the same level of indentation

Comment: i copy and pasted your code into their and it still wont work

Comment: @user3213259 look at this. http://puu.sh/6WnV8.png. The two are not indented to the same level.  Indent them to the same level.

Comment: @user3213259 where it says 'content' click in front of the 'c'.  Press space, once.

Comment: thanks that cleared that error message....now its talking about the line right below it

Comment: Thats a different question.  Make a new question.