# Correctly calling and loading external variables during parallelisation

Tags: python, c, parallel-processing

I am going to be using C to parallelise a giant task in python. The python script is available [here](http://pastebin.com/ze66EgDE). The attached script is the working prototype for a single density (`dens`) column. The next step is to turn this into a Monte Carlo simulation by calling 1000 new `dens` columns (sequentially) which are already created in files named `0001.txt - 1000.txt` (each with one single column of `dens` values corresponding to the `nodes`).

Obviously the first step is to strip `dens` from the following line…

```
x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2, dens = np.loadtxt('nodes.txt', delimiter=' ', usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), unpack=True)
```

…which is easy enough. The following lines were created to solve the initial problem within the script itself, which give an idea of what I am trying to do…

```
x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2 = np.loadtxt('nodes.txt', delimiter=' ', usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), unpack=True)
for i in range (1,1001):
    dens, = np.loadtxt('{:0>4}.txt'.format(i), delimiter=' ', usecols=(0), unpack=True
```

…but I have been informed that this will not allow for parallelisation on our cluster and I need to use something in the command line like…

```
python myscript.py 000.txt
```

**My question is how would I code `dens` into the script so that the above command prompt would work?**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) page which displays options like…

```
from subprocess import call
call([])
```

and

```
os.system
```

…but I am not entirely sure how to adapt it so that it is calling the correct variable to the correct place. Apologies if this is a simple solution, but I have been thrown into the deep end with python and I am still struggling to get my feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833/855026) shows you how to get the command line inputs from python:

```py
import sys
print sys.argv
```

So you might use

```py
filename = sys.argv[1]
dens, = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=' ', usecols=(0), unpack=True)
```

Of course, you should add your own error checking.