# Read user input numbers and perform a calculation in Python

Tags: python

please help me... "Read in two numbers from user input without a prompt, add them, and print the result. 
 Hint: Use int() to convert the numbers to integers.

Note: These activities may test code with different test values. This activity will perform two tests: the first with num1 = 5 and num2 = 10, the second with num1 = 6 and num2 = 3. "

I tried just doing one and it didn't work but I can't wrap my head around how to do two tests let alone one...
I tried this so far and it came out with 510..noob please help

```
num1=int(input(5)) 
num2=int(input(10))
num3=num1 + num2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: user input and commandline arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-user-input-and-commandline-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact you need just:

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = num1+num2
print(num3)
```

Answer (score 4):

The argument to the input() function is the string to display as a prompt.

In your case, you'd want that to be simply input().

Comment: also `input()` evaluates to `int` automatically so you could remove that to just `num1=input()`

Comment: @depperm: Are you sure about that? The return value of input() is always a Type 'str'.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: it evaluates it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python

Comment: Ahh I see, the input() function in Python2.x has different behavior. My answer is only valid for Python3.x where raw_input and input are the same.

Learnt something new today. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass parameters into `input`. You're asking the *user* for input.

I don't think the assignment is asking you to write your own tests. I think it's saying that whatever code you give it will be tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
person_name = input()
person_age = int(input())
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. It does not contain any code to perform a calculation