# python set arguments option for function in command line

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have written simple function to cut lines in txt file, takes 3 arguments :

> cut(inicial_line, final_line, file)

now how do i put inicial_line and final_line to -c option to execute it for example:

> $ python cut.py -c 5 8 f.txt

and it print file text from 5th to 8th line

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.argv)` should get you started...

Comment: There's information on using command-line arguments in Python in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70797/3775798). Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Take a look at the ``argparse`` module: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Im using python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution

> ```
> __name__=='__main__':
>         import argparse
>         import sys
>         pars = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>         pars.add_argument('-n', nargs=2, type=int)
>         args=pars.parse_args(sys.argv[1:4])
>         print cut(args.n[0], args.n[1], sys.argv[4])
> ```

main problem was **args=pars.parse_args(sys.argv[1:4])**

i didnt know that **args=pars.parse_args()** is the same as **args=pars.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])**