# How to make a python program accept an input

Tags: python

I have written the following program and it works as expected however I would like the user to input something
This is my code:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from math import log10

def maxnum(x):
    return ''.join(str(n) for n in sorted(x, reverse=True,
                          key=lambda i: Fraction(i, 10**(int(log10(i))+1)-1)))

for numbers in [(1, 34, 3, 98, 9, 76, 45, 4), (54, 546, 548, 60)]:
    print('Numbers: %r\n  Largest integer: %15s' % (numbers, maxnum(numbers)))
```

I would like it to print out "enter the numbers" user inputs the numbers he would like to concatenate into a larger number and then the program outputs it in the same way as the code above.
How do I do that
Thanks in advance

Comment: [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is the function you're looking for

Comment: This has been discussed in depth in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-user-input-and-commandline-arguments)

Comment: What I would like to do is replace (1, 34, 3, 98, 9, 76, 45, 4), (54, 546, 548, 60 with what the user entered

Comment: Then there's also another answer for you https://stackoverflow.com/q/4663306/6622817

Answer (score -1):

Try following a tutorial like http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html

```
person = input('Enter your name: ')
print('Hello', person)
```