# Why does input() seem to result in executing the entered text?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been learning Python and have encountered an error displaying the result of using `input`. My mistake still eludes even after: [Python Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-user-input-and-commandline-arguments), [Py Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/print.html) and many others.

My expected output would be what the user types but instead I get a syntax error on line 7 `test_two = input...`

```
# test program

test_one = 'bob'
print (test_one)
print test_one

test_two = input('What is your city? ')

print "City: ", test_two
```

I am unable to spot what is different to many of the examples I have seen.  It seems like its doing an `eval` on the entered text?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   
   File ".\test.py", line 7, in <module>
     test_two = input('What is your city?')   
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
 NameError: name 'Paris' is not defined
```

Comment: Use `raw_input`. `input` perfoms an `eval` on whatever text is input. `raw_input` is renamed to `input` in python 3.

Comment: Because `input()` uses `eval()` to execute the entered text. Use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: Interesting.  I started with ``raw_input` however when running under debugger on Microsoft vscode, the input would be multiple lines and would never stop.  Maybe there is a problem with the  Extension.  I will investigate.