# How do I use raw_input() with a user defined function?

Tags: python

How do I get an input from the user to be used as grade?

```
def grade_converter(grade):
        if grade >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif grade >= 80:
            return "B"
        elif grade >= 70:
         return "C"
        elif grade >= 65:
            return "D"
        else:
            return "F"
```

Comment: `grade_converter` accepts an integer, so you'll have to turn the string you get from `raw_input` into an integer and then send it to `grade_converter`.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. I did a search for how to read user input in python and I came across the following post with the title `Python: user input and commandline arguments` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-user-input-and-commandline-arguments. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input()` returns a *string*, but your function is comparing against *integers*. Convert your input to an integer before calling `grade_converter()`:

```
grade = int(raw_input('Enter a grade'))
print grade_converter(grade)
```

Note that the conversion will raise an exception if you enter something that can't be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3, `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`. You could just use it as an input to  your `grade_converter()` function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Enter a score')
    print('The grade is: ', grade_converter(int(input())))
```

Comment: But if the OP is using `raw_input()`, they must be using Python 2.

Comment: Agreed, hence why I mentioned Python3. Besides, Python2 is nearing its EOL, so I figured a little suggestion about Python3 may be helpful.