# Expression input from user in python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to take an algebraic expression as an input from the user?
e.g  x^2 + sin(x)
e.g. sin(x) +cos(x) 
something like that and solve for some value of x
In Java, we use buffered reader and expression input functions, but in python3.x what I have to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User input and command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/user-input-and-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Please edit to make your question more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-i-read-from-stdin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `input()` function in Python 3.

```py
x = input()
print(x + " World")

>>> Hello
Hello World


x = input("Type a number: ")
print(int(x) * 2)

>>> Type a number: 5
10
```