# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable with input()

Tags: python, input, error-handling

I have the following code, which is supposed to ask the user 2 file names. I get an error with the input() in the second function but not in the first, I don't understand...
Here is the error :

> output = getOutputFile()
>     File "splitRAW.py", line 22, in getOutputFile
>       fileName = input("\t=> ")
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
# Loops until an existing file has been found
def getInputFile():
    print("Which file do you want to split ?")
    fileName = input("\t=> ")
    while 1:
        try:
            file = open(fileName, "r")
            print("Existing file, let's continue !")
            return(fileName)
        except IOError:
            print("No such existing file...")
            print("Which file do you want to split ?")
            fileName = input("\t=> ")

# Gets an output file from user
def getOutputFile():
    print("What name for the output file ?")
    fileName = input("\t=> ")
```

And here is my main() :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = getInputFile()
    output = getOutputFile()
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you've defined `input = something_here`. Depending on your IDE, it may have have been in a different file or within the console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is when you say `input = getInputFile()`.

More specifically:

1. The program enters the `getInputFile()` function, and `input` hasn't been assigned yet. That means the Python interpreter will use the built-in `input`, as you intended.
2. You return `filename` and get out of `getInputFile()`. The interpreter now overwrites the name `input` to be that string.
3. `getOutputFile()` now tries to use `input`, but it's been replaced with your file name string. You can't call a string, so the interpreter tells you that and throws an error.

Try replacing `input = getInputFile()` with some other variable, like `fileIn = getInputFile()`.

Also, your `getOutputFile()` is not returning anything, so your `output` variable will just have `None` in it.

Comment: Take away message is, don't name variables similar to function names.

Answer (score 1):

You may be overriding the input name with something else.

If you need to reinitialize the input function in a notebook:

```
from builtin import input
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time just "**RESTART YOUR KERNEL**" TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - restart kernel and its gone. You're good to go.

Comment: First need to change the variable name input to some other variable because python interpreter is confused, and then restart the kernel

Comment: Restarting kernel resolves my problem. In my case, I used jupyter notebook in VS code with simple code `a = input()`, got *TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*.

Answer (score -3):

[Depending on what version of python you're using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/user-input-and-command-line-arguments):

Python 2:

```
var = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
print "you entered", var
```

Or for Python 3:

```
var = input("Please enter something: ")
print("You entered: " + var)
```

Comment: No, that is not the issue. They have trampled over the `input` builtin as the error conveys