# Activity 1 of task 1 prompt a user to input firstname, lastname and initials

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi everyone I have been trying to figure out the best way to do this question I have to fix for my task 1. The teacher asks me to not hard code the answer or the name because I have to prompt user input. These are his errors he wrote out:
Activity 1: 2 errors
By the end of it I should be able to prompt him to enter a first name, a last name and initials without hard coding

[image]

By the way this is my code I have attempted so far:
Activity 1 Part B is fine he said but its just part A and Activity 2

[image: attempted code I have done]

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User input and command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/user-input-and-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score -1):

You can directly assign `firstname = "Firstname Joseph lastname Carlos"`