# How to ask for input to slice a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a list if 10,000 URLs that I need to check and I'm automatizing the process of opening those URLs.

So far, I've done this and it works:

```
import webbrowser
import pandas as pd

urls  = pd.read_csv('urls.csv', delimiter='\'')

urls = urls['urls']

for url in urls[:100]:
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

Now, the problem is that with this I have to go to the code and change the slicing every time I need new URLs to be open.
Do you think is possible to ask for an input to the users in order to select by themselves the range of slicing?

I've tried this:

```
for url in urls[{''}:{''}].format(input('Enter first line:  '), input('Enter last line:   ')):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with 
these indexers [{''}] of <class 'set'>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What is the content of your csv file ? can you provide a minimal csv file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: @Vishnudev Nop, it doesn't.

Comment: What are you facing issue with? Iterating the dataframe or taking input from user in python?

Comment: @PrinceFrancis just one columns =['urls'] that contains urls such as https://www.google.com

Comment: @Vishnudev The error occurs when trying to take input from user to slice df

Comment: @pyseo Where is that code? Can I know reason behind asking the user for slice range?

Comment: @Vishnudev I'm sorry, I totally forgot to put it in the question... I've just added!

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/user-input-and-command-line-arguments

Comment: @Vishnudev It returns the same error

Comment: What is the reasoning behind slicing? Why not iterate through whole list?

Comment: `slice_idx = int(input('Enter index to slice at: '))` and then `urls.loc[:slice_idx, 'urls']`

Comment: Where the code says `urls  = pd.read_csv('urls.csv', delimiter='\'')`, why does it (correctly!) **not** say `urls = pd.read_csv({''}, delimiter={''}).format('urls.csv', '\'')`? Does this give you some insight as to what is wrong with the current attempt? if you wanted to use a an existing variable `filename` to give the name of the file to open, how would you write that? That would look like... `urls = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='\'')`, right? Do you understand why? So....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
slice_idx = int(input('Enter index to slice at: '))
```

to get the index to slice at and then

```
urls.loc[:slice_idx, 'urls']
```

to get series of sliced urls.

Answer (score 0):

If limiting the amount of URLs to check and the library are not mandatory, you could try request library.

Something like:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls  = pd.read_csv('urls.csv', delimiter='\'')

urls = urls['urls']

results = []

for url in urls:

    request = requests.get(url)

    if request.status_code == 200:
        results.append(url)
```

Bare in mind that with this aproach, URLs should have `http://` in the csv file. For example http://www.someweb.com