# How do I read from the terminal in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to use os.system("dir") and also be able to save the text outputted to a variable.  I tried using `sys.stdout.read()` but running `sys.stdout.readable()` returns `False`.  Do you know how I can read from the terminal?

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833/2299087

Comment: Did you want `sys.stdin` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using os library:

```
info = os.popen('dir').read()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) method

Example

```py
import subprocess as sp

stdout = sp.check_output("dir")
print(stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion here about the different streams, and possibly a better way to do things.

For the specific case of `dir`, you can replace the functionality you want with the [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) function, or better yet [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir).

For the more general case, you will not be able to read an arbitrary `stdout` stream. If you want to do that, you'll have to set up a [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) whose I/O streams you control. This is not much more complicated than using `os.system`. you can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), for example:

```
content = subprocess.run("dir", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True).stdout
```

The object returned by `run` has a `stdout` attribute that contains everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read just go with

```
x = input()
```

This reads a one line from the terminal. `x` is a string by default, but you can cast it, say to int, like so

```
x = int(x)
```