# How to create a menu in Python?

Tags: python, menu, display

My classmates and I started studying Python, and one of the problems we encountered is how to design a menu that does the following:

1. Read a 4-digit number, display the largest digit and report whether it is odd or even.
2. Read two 3-digit numbers, form a third number with the highest of the first and the lowest of the second.
3. Read a 3-digit number and form the largest number possible with your digits.
4. Exit

Comment: Could you include the code that you've tried and the places where you think it may be failing?

Comment: def function1():
    num = input("Type a 4-digit number: ") 
    num = list(num) 
    maxNum = int(max(num)) 
    if maxNum%2 == 0: 
        print("Number: ", maxNum, 'It's even') 
    else:
        print("Number: ", maxNum, 'It's odd')

Comment: I don't know if this code is good. If not, help me please :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use for loop with some variables respectively for the lowest and highest  number or the built-in min(), max() functions done the same.
To read input use input("here is some prompt message")
more here:
[link] [How to prompt for user input and read command-line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/how-to-prompt-for-user-input-and-read-command-line-arguments)
hope it help you out!

Comment: Thank you very much :)